# Spring Integration Gateway - BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

My bean definition,

```
<int:gateway id="myGateway" 
       service-interface="a.b.c.MyGateway"
       default-request-channel="myChannel" />
```

Exception,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myGateway': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:247) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:807) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:737) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:529) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:356) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489) ~[spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
```

What could be the cause ?

Comment: Possibly a class loader issue? What version of Spring Integration (I see you have spring 3.2.8)? Try running with -verbose and watch the class loading.

Comment: Try to figure out if you have several `myGateway` bean definitions. That exception does not make sense in case of custom `<int:gateway>` tag.

Comment: @GaryRussell I am using 4.1.6-RELEASE version of spring integration.

Comment: With SI 4.1 you must use SF 4.1. Although you exactly do that as a transitive dependency... So, try to get rid of the SF  3.2 and come back to us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Integration 4.1.x requires Spring Framework 4.1.x; it is not compatible with Spring Framework 3.x - the `Message` etc abstraction was moved to `spring-framework-messaging` in 4.0.

Always check [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/preface.html#supported-spring-versions) for compatibility.